# OSX 10.9.1 unable to open .pkg file

Tags: osx

I downloaded gfortran-4.8.2.pkg from http://coudert.name/software/gfortran-4.8.2-Mavericks.dmg but somehow 
I could not open it .

I unpacked it, right clicked so, the menu was appeared,

it said Open with and 
I said installer but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy the unpacked directory to your applications directory and try opening it through spotlight.

Comment: Please explain what is going on. I'd be *very* wary of a one-line instruction from the left field I can't check for sanity... not knowing squat on OSX I'll have to leave comments as to sanity/correctness to experts.

Answer (score 0):

Unpacked it? With what? DMG files don't need to be unpacked, you should just be able to double-click it and have it open.

If you ls -l it in a Terminal window, what do you see?

Comment: @Vonbrand The unpacked file gfortran.pkg file is in applications. When I right click it and say open an follow yhe instructions the menu is appeared and then what should I do ??

Comment: I do not see gfortran when I did ls -l.